# Simple innerHTML update not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, innerhtml

Long story short, I'm enhancing an existing registration form to perform a simple "are you human" check.  Easy stuff (one would think).   I haven't even gotten to the good stuff yet, because I can't seem to set the innerHTML of a couple `span` elements on the page.

Here's the stripped down code...

```
<form method="post" action="register2.php">Please verify that you are human below...
    <br/> <span id="num1"></span> X
    <input id="num2" style="width:20px" /> equals <span id="answer"></span>

    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

And the stripped down script...

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
var answer = num1 * num2;

$('#num1').innerHTML = "" + num1;
$('#answer').innterHTML = "" + answer;
```

At this point... I would just like to see the last two lines set the correct form elements so that I can continue to work on the validation functions.   I must have a typo or logic error in here... thoughts?

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/2e9Xc/

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `.innerHTML` instead of `.html()` since you're using jQuery?

Comment: use .html('value') instead.

Comment: Grrr...  thanks guys.   That's it.   Must be having a brain fart this morning.

Comment: every one who had puted the downvote for me why no reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#num1').html(num1);
$('#answer').html(answer);
```

Since you already have jQuery loaded using the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is best.

See: http://api.jquery.com/html/

If you insist on using `innerHTML` you need to get a proper DOM object from the jQuery object like this:

```
$('#num1')[0].innerHTML = "" + num1;
$('#answer')[0].innterHTML = "" + answer;
```

Comment: +1 good answer + you had not used `(string)` in `.html()`

Answer (score 3):

`.innerHTML` is a property of a DOM element.

```
document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = "" + num1;
```

`html()` is the jQuery function to use instead of `innerHTML`:

```
$('#num1').html(num1);
```

Comment: update `$('#num1').html("" + num1);` to `$('#num1').html(num1);` and I will put a +1 for you. Check my answer to get what I mean.

Comment: @imsiso That's true, I guess it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `InnerHTML` on a JQuery object. You use the `html()` method instead. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="register2.php">Please verify that you are human below...
    <br/> <span id="num1"></span> X
    <input id="num2" style="width:20px" /> equals <span id="answer"></span>

    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
var answer = num1 * num2;

$('#num1').html(num1);
$('#answer').html(answer);
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/2e9Xc/1/

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$('#num1').html("" + num1);
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is best choice.